# Determine equilibrium stability transition of a reaction (function of temp and concentrations)

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium

I am trying to calculate and plot the stability of $\ce{Fe3O4 - FeS2}$ based on the chemical equation:

$$ \ce{Fe3O4(s) + 6SO2(g) + 16CO(g) -> 3FeS2 (s) + 16CO2(g)} \tag{1} $$

I want to plot the transition from $\ce{Fe3O4}$ to $\ce{FeS2}$, in a plot of the concentration/fugacity of $\ce{SO2(g)}$ as a function of temperature.

I have available the following thermochemical data $a_i$ for each individual molecule's formation reaction,

$$ \ln(K) = \frac{a_1}{T} + a_2 \ln T + a_3 + a_4 T + a_5T^2 \tag{2} $$
where the $a$'s are the fit coefficients I have available for each of the species above, and $\ln(K)$ is
$$ \ln\overline{K}_i(T) = -\frac{\Delta_\mathrm{r}G_i(T)}{RT} \tag{3} $$

How can I produce an image like [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/369235618/figure/fig5/AS:11431281126875553@1678853278026/Oxygen-fugacity-diagram-Oxygen-fugacity-is-buffered-by-minerals-MH-magnetite-hematite.png)? (Complete [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/369235618_Routes_to_reduction_of_phosphate_by_high-energy_events), not relevant for calculation)

Edit: I'll be online and working on this all day, so if you have comments/further questions please comment them and I'll respond as soon as possible!
for reference, the fit coefficients for each species

```
species_data = {
    "Fe3O4": {"a1": 4.0276612308074633e+05, "a2": -9.4661523582307066e+00, "a3": -6.9502410801855703e+01, "a4": 1.5085130307144656e-02, "a5": -1.9444510158593611e-06},
    "FeS2": {"a1": 1.3624235215287484e+05, "a2":-5.2169286395159462e+00 , "a3": -2.4724164596373562e+01, "a4":7.2462091584085467e-03, "a5": -1.2248091281633105e-06},
    "SO2": {"a1": 1.3624235215287484e+05, "a2":  -5.2169286395159462e+00, "a3": -2.4724164596373562e+01, "a4":  7.2462091584085467e-03, "a5": -1.2248091281633105e-06 },
    "CO": {"a1": 1.2899777785630804e+05, "a2": -1.7549835812545211e+00 , "a3": -3.1625806804795502e+00  , "a4": 4.1336204683783961e-04 , "a5":  -2.3579962985989574e-08},
    "CO2": {"a1": 1.9284060511825030e+05, "a2": -2.7725941201250066e+00 , "a3": -1.4374508628203330e+01, "a4": 9.5527761423722102e-04, "a5":  -5.3273135070236439e-08},
}
```

Comment: I may be able to help, but something is suspicious. Firstly, could you send the original research paper from which your image comes from? Secondly, the concept of equilibrium constant $K$ refers to a *chemical reaction*, not to a particular species. There is no such thing as an 'equilibrium constant for oxygen', but we could have a $K$ for that reaction you posted. Thus, what does those $K$'s refer to? To the formation reaction of each species?

Comment: @MetalStorm thanks for responding! You are right, the constant K refers to the formation reaction of each species (I'll edit the post for clarity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we apply Gibbs' phase rule so we know the number of intensive variables we need to fix so that the equilibrium state of the system is established. We have

- Five different species, i.e. $N = 5$.
- Three phases, one gas phase and two solid phases of magnetite and iron(ii) disulfide. Thus, $\pi = 3$.
- One chemical reaction, i.e. $r = 1 $.

So we have
\begin{align}
  F &= 2 - \pi + N - r \\
    &= 2 - 3 + 5 - 1 \rightarrow F = 3 \tag{1}
\end{align}
and we need to specify $3$ intensive variables.

---

Since the activity of a pure solid phase is one, the law of mass action yields
\begin{align}
  K &= \frac{a_\ce{FeS2}^{3}\hat{f}_\ce{CO2}^{16}}
            {a_\ce{Fe3O4}\hat{f}_\ce{SO2}^{6}\hat{f}_\ce{CO}^{16}} \\
  &= \frac{\hat{f}_\ce{CO2}^{16}}{\hat{f}_\ce{SO2}^{6}\hat{f}_\ce{CO}^{16}} \tag{2}
  \\
\end{align}
The fugacity of a species in the gas phase is a function of the pressure, temperature, and composition. I will assume that the gas phase behaves ideally. If this is not valid, just say in the comments and we can take into account the non-ideality. For the ideal case, the fugacity is equal to the partial pressure
\begin{align}
  K &=
  \dfrac{\left(\dfrac{y_\ce{CO2}p}{p^\circ}\right)^{16}}
        {\left(\dfrac{y_\ce{SO2}p}{p^\circ}\right)^{6}\
         \left(\dfrac{y_\ce{CO}p}{p^\circ}\right)^{16}} \\
  &= \left(\frac{p^\circ}{p}\right)^6
           \frac{y_\ce{CO2}^{16}}{y_\ce{SO2}^6y_\ce{CO}^{16}} \tag{3}
\end{align}
where $p^\circ = \pu{1 bar}$ is the standard pressure. Finally, we combine Eq. (3) with the relation $ y_\ce{CO2} = 1 - y_\ce{CO} - y_\ce{SO2}$
\begin{equation}
  \boxed{K(T)
   = \left(\frac{p^\circ}{p}\right)^6
   \frac{(1 - y_\ce{CO} - y_\ce{SO2})^{16}}{y_\ce{SO2}^6y_\ce{CO}^{16}}} \tag{4}
\end{equation}
Eq. (4) is a non-linear equation with $4$ unknowns which are $p$, $T$, $y_\ce{CO}$ and $y_\ce{SO2}$. Once we set three of them, we can solve for the remaining one, which agrees with Gibbs' phase rule. The simplest algorithm in my opinion would be:

- Set a temperature $T$. This allows the calculation of $K$ because you have the Gibbs' free energy of formation for each chemical species.
- Set the pressure $p$ of interest.
- Set one molar fraction.
- Solve the equation. You will have now the x value which is $T$, and the y value can be calculated with $\hat{f}_\ce{SO2} = y_\ce{SO2}(p/p^\circ)$.

Comment: thanks for your response!! I agree/understand up to Eq. (4). I am then confused by the algorithm you've laid out. Not sure what you mean by set a temperature, if i'm trying to vary T in the end. So unsure how to calculate K. I know I can get Delta G for the reaction, by using the parametrisation for theGibbs' free energy of formation for each chemical species, and subtracting the products'-reactants'.  Unsure how to proceed from there.

Comment: Set a temperature = Give a value to the temperature, e.g. $T = \pu{350 K}$. Once you solve the equation, then you do the same for $T = \pu{360 K}$, and so forth. If you solve the equation for $10$ temperatures, you will have $10$ points for the curve.

Comment: ok cool that makes sense. Similar Q about the y_CO, since that is an unknown and I'd be solving for y_SO2?

Comment: @learning_physics Yes, that's right.

Comment: The problem is that if you mix $\ce{Fe3O4, SO2, CO}$, you will never obtain $\ce{FeS2}$, whatever the temperature and the pressure. The activation energy is too high.

Comment: @Maurice Hello Maurice. I answered directly the question, but I didn't bother to check its characteristics. Why do you say the activation energy is too high? By just looking at the reaction?

Comment: @Metal Storm. First a reaction between three products is rare. Second I know that $\ce{Fe3O4}$ is used to produce metallic iron in the steel industry by heating it tumor than 1000°C. I also know that $\ce{FeS2}$ can not be made in lab as it need high temperature and high pressure to be made in geological times, out of any oxygen around. And here, there is plenty of oxygen atoms, contained in oxides of course. But it must be extremely difficult (nearly impossible) to synthesize $\ce{FeS2}$ out of such a mixture, even at high temperature. This is why the activation energy must be high.

Comment: @Maurice I completely agree with all your observations. In fact, the curves that the OP shows in the paper support your claim (even though they refer to other reactions). The fugacity of oxygen is extremely low (and $\ce{O2}$ is a product in those reactions), which means that in equilibrium the reaction barely took place. However, the OP asked how to calculate the curve, so I didn't bother on the feasibility. I will try to edit the post and add your remarks, when  I do some calculations. Thanks.